# Cat so spooked of me she attacks and stalks

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression, fear

That's my first post so be patient with me please:)

My bf and I moved into a new flat with a couple we know for ages (their cat knows us very well and used to love sitting on my lap).
The move unsettled the cat greatly and she went from being an incredibly cuddly but at times moody princess to a cat who thinks attack is the best defence.
Our friends didn't do the safe room procedure and that might have something to do with it. First her food and toilet were in the kitchen and if I would come in first thing in the morning she was rubbing against me. As soon as I turned my back on her though she would attack my calves, like a hit, and run attack. It happened almost every morning for almost 2 weeks in different spots around the flat. She would be all lovey dovey and go around my legs to the point of tripping me, then attack. She would continue to stalk me for a short distance as well. It came to a point where, when I saw her standing there staring at me that I would put on my wellies and take a towel with me.
I stopped feeding her right away because I suspected it had something to do with food aggression due to the move and it got slightly better, also because I was careful around her and never turned my back. After 2 weeks our friends decided to lock her in their bedroom at night because she was still really upset and suddenly she turned almost back into her old self.
Now she occasionally comes up to me and does that frantic leg rubbing again (end of week 3). I haven't touched her in quite a while because I don't want to get scratched and the more frantic the leg rubbing the more I know she could turn aggressive when I touch her. Just now she did that again and looked at my hands pleadingly, and when I dangled them down she rubbed against them with the same frantic movements. I made the mistake of opening my hand and her back stroked against it and I saw the frantic bottle tail warning me.
A loud no and not turning my back and a towel as distraction worked to not get me attacked but she sure was stalking me.

I'm really fed up and every interaction with her gets my heart pounding. It's been 3 weeks now and my 2 friends have no clue what they can do about it. Spraying catnip to make her comfortable seems to increase the likelihood of an attack at that very spot (favorite rug is next to kitchen).

Also, she is pretty overweight so they don't want me giving her any treats. Not that I feel like it at the moment lol.

Does anyone have any ideas here? She attacked maybe three times my boyfriend as well, but generally seems to tolerate him better. She doesn't want to be touched by him either though and starts hissing. Sitting on his or my lap is still OK though.

My 2 friends can handle her without any issues. They are telling me I should be resolute with the cat but I don't want to go down a rabbit hole of confrontation (tried it once by blowing on her, got a loud growling in response). I'm sure she'd claw me if I were to push her aside.
Also, she doesn't really play but gets bored easily so my friends think that she is play aggressive with me and provokes me for a reaction. I just want to be left alone at that point.

I forgot to say just yesterday she was blinking at me and enjoyed me stroking her head for the first time in a while which I thought was a good sign. She wasn't in frantic leg rubbing mode at the time though.